# Popup can have only one widget as content

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I work on a kivy interface. I try to implement a popup but when I press the button that should fire the popup I get the error `kivy.uix.popup.PopupException: Popup can have only one widget as content` (full console logs below).

The minimal reproducible example I prepared consists of 3 files; **main.py**, **my.kv**, and **mygrid.py**.

How can I achieve that pressing the button triggers the popup without altering the architecture of the modules?

### my.kv

Contains the structure of `<GridLayout>` (green section) and `<ScrollView>` (blue section)

```
<ScrollView>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<GridLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 1, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height

    Button:
        width: root.width
        text: "Submit"
        on_press:root.SendButton()
        size_hint: 1, None
```

### mygrid.py

Contains the logic regarding `<GridLayout>`. In the example case, it only decides when to fire a popup

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def SendButton(self):
        from main import myApp
        myApp().show_popup()
```

### main.py

Run the application

- Nest `<GridLayout>` in `<ScrollView>`
- Define the popup

  ```
  import kivy
  from kivy.app import App
  from mygrid import MyGrid
  from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
  from kivy.core.window import Window
  from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
  from kivy.lang import Builder

  Builder.load_string('''
  <CustomPopup>:
      size_hint: .5, .5
      auto_dismiss: False
      title: 'Hello world'
      Button:
          text: 'Click me to dismiss'
          on_press: root.dismiss()

  ''')

  class CustomPopup(Popup):
      pass

  class myApp(App):
      def build(self):
          layout = MyGrid(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
          layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
          root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
          root.add_widget(layout)
          return root

      def show_popup(self):
          p = CustomPopup()
          p.open()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      myApp().run()
  ```

### Full console logs:

```
PS C:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre>  & 'C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\EXO\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51462' '--' 'c:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre\main.py'
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\EXO\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-07-29_14.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1 
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5 
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\_
_init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.17461 git hash: b790affce32e)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc. (Intel)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Intel, Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 Direct3D11 vs_4_1 ps_4_1, D3D11-
9.17.10.4459)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00 (ANGLE 2.1.17461 git hash: b790affce32e)'>       
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre\main.py", line 36, in <module>
     myApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp        
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input     
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1664, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1701, in on_touch_up
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 968, in on_touch_up
     if self.dispatch('on_scroll_stop', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 1005, in on_scroll_stop
     self.simulate_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 668, in simulate_touch_down
     ret = super(ScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "c:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre\my.kv", line 23, in <module>
     on_press:root.SendButton()
   File "c:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre\mygrid.py", line 6, in SendButton
     myApp().show_popup()
   File "c:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre\main.py", line 32, in show_popup
     p = CustomPopup()
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\modalview.py", line 195, in __init__  
     super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\anchorlayout.py", line 68, in __init__
     super(AnchorLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__      
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 366, in __init__     
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 540, in apply      
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     widget.add_widget(child)
   File "C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\popup.py", line 216, in add_widget    
     raise PopupException(
 kivy.uix.popup.PopupException: Popup can have only one widget as content
PS C:\Users\EXO\Desktop\mre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code:

```
def SendButton(self):
    from main import myApp
    myApp().show_popup()
```

The `import` here causes the `Builder.load_string()` in `main.py` to be executed a second time (the first was when you ran the `App`). And that second execution causes the `<CustomPopup>` rule to be loaded twice which results in the `CustomPopup` rule trying to put two `Buttons` in the `Popup`, and trigger the error message.

Also, this is creating another instance of `myApp` (`myApp()` always creates a new instance). And then calls the `show_popup()` method of that new instance. A better approach is to not do an import in the `SendButton()` method, and just call the `show_popup()` method of the running `App`. Like this:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def SendButton(self):
        App.get_running_app().show_popup()
```

This code gets the currently running `App` and calls its `show_popup()` method without importing anything from `main.py`.